# Natural logarithmic derivative trick

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Hi chaps and chapesses,

I was wondering if someone could just explain something.

If I have a function which is dependent on $x$, the familiar $f(x)$. Now, if I take the derivative of this, and multiple by $x$ and divide through by $f(x)$.

How does this then become true:

$$
\frac{x}{f(x)}\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}=\frac{d\ln{f(x)}}{d\ln{x}}
$$

I'm thinking I'm either a.) tired, b.) stupud or c.) both

Comment: "chaps and chapesses"- Interesting?

Comment: It's a British thing. :)

Comment: What does $\frac{df(x)}{d\ln x}$ mean? I mean, $\frac{df}{dx}$ means "the derivative of $f$ in terms of $x$", and since $x$ is a variable in $f$, we know this is defined as $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h},$$ but your expression is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac{x}{f(x)}\frac{d(f(x))}{dx}=\frac{x}{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)=x\cdot \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$
$=\large\frac{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}{\frac{1}{x}}=\large\frac{\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(f(x))]}{\frac{d}{dx}[\ln x]}=\frac{d\ln{f(x)}}{d\ln{x}}$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to Aniket's answer, we can carefully specify what we mean by $d\ln(x)$ and still get the same result. I'll work from right to left. Let $y(x) = \ln(x)$, whence $x(y) = e^y$. We compute the derivative with respect to $y$ $$
\frac{d}{dy} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{dx}{dy} \frac{1}{f(x)} \frac{d}{dx} f(x).$$
We have that $x(y) = e^y$ so that $\frac{dx}{dy} = e^y = x$. Thus we can write
$$\frac{d}{dy} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{dx}{dy}\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{x}{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x).$$
This is the meaning of the symbol $\frac{d\ln(f(x))}{d\ln(x)}$.